# Образование слов "гавкать", "каркать", "мычать"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Почему:

гав-гав -> гавкать;

мяу-мяу -> мяукать;

кар-кар -> каркать;

пи-пи -> пикать;

фу-фу -> фукать;

ну-ну -> нукать;

Но:

м**у** -> м**ыч**ать?

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, корова при мычании издаёт не "му", а  М-М-М-М - сонорный, который можно "пропеть", а вот гласный между этими М что-то среднее между "у", "о" и "ы". В немецком-muh, в английском - moo-moo.   В русском языке - му, а вообще-то что-то нечленораздельное, как, например, немые пытаются что-то произнести нечленораздельное, мы же говорим о них, что они мычат, вот и корова мычит.

Поэтому и закрепилась форма"мЫчать", а если бы точно слышалось му, мы бы сказали, что она "мукает". Только это звучит некрасиво, а мучит - глагол с совсем другим значением, как и мыкать (горе мыкать). Так что только мычать остаётся.