# Этимология слова «икота»

Tags: этимология

Является ли слово "икота" этимологически однокоренным с гласной буквой "и" (по аналогии с [пи->пикать](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449156/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C))?

Answer (score 2):

Существительное **ико́та** (корень **-ик-**; суффикс **-от**; окончание **-а** — по Тихонову) произошло от звукоподражательного глагола **ика́ть** (корень **-ик-**; суффикс **-а**; глагольное окончание **-ть**).
[Ика́ть — издавать отрывистые непроизвольные звуки, вызванные судорожным сокращением диафрагмы. (См. [список](https://moluch.ru/archive/181/46683/) звукоподражательных глаголов.)]

Вот что говорится в [этимологических словарях](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B8/%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

**ика́ть** (Г. Крылов)
Образовано с помощью глагольного суффикса от звукоподражательного *ик*.

**ика́ть**,  ика́ю, заи́ка, заика́ться (М. Фасмер)
укр. ïка́ти, болг. и́кам «икаю», сербохорв. и̏цати се, а также jȅцати «рыдать», словен. íkati «рыдать», чеш. jíkati «икать; заикаться», польск. диал. ikać «икать», в.-луж. hikać, jukać, «икать», н.-луж. hykaś. Звукоподражание, подобно франц. hoquet **«икота»**; слав. формы, вероятно, возникли отчасти независимо друг от друга.

Есть другой глагол: **и́кать** — произносить звук [и] на месте написания букв «е» и «я» в предударных слогах (корень **-и-**; суффикс **-ка**; глагольное окончание **-ть**).
От него образовано существительное **и́канье** (сравните: а́кать — а́канье; о́кать — о́канье).